# Trying to make a transaction with node-mssql using a for loop

Tags: node.js, sql-server, loops, callback

I desperately try to insert into a table several requests using a for loop. The code is supposed to iterate through an array of object and generate SQL requests. The code is based on the node-mssql documentation. If something goes wrong during the process, a rollback is fired, else, at the end of the operation, a commit is fired. I believe I should use the result parameter of the callback but I'm not sure how. If I console.log errors, I get "Can't acquire connection for the request. There is another request in progress."

```
const connexion_test = async(info)=> 
{

    var test = [{name:"AB",surname:"BC"},{name:"DE",surname:"EF"},{name:"FG",surname:"GH"},{name:"HI",surname:"HJ"}];
    let pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
    const transaction = new sql.Transaction(pool)

    transaction.begin
    (err => {
        let rolledBack = false
        transaction.on
        ('rollback', aborted => 
        {
            // emited with aborted === true
    
            rolledBack = true
        })
    for (let i=0;i<test.length;i++) 
    {
        new sql.Request(transaction)
        .query
        (`insert into table_test (nom, prenom) values ('${test[i].name}','${test[i].surname}')`, (err, result) => 
        {
            if (err) 
            {    
                if (!rolledBack) 
                {
                    transaction.rollback
                    (err => 
                        { 

                        }
                    )  
                }
            }
            else
            { 
              if (i == 0) {
             
              transaction.commit(err => {

            
                })
              }
            }
        }
        )
           
    }
})
     
}
```

This is a tough one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure about the error, but you are only committing the transaction `if (i == 0)` so that will only execute on the first run. Also you are injecting your data instead of using parameters. You should probably scrap all this code and just use a bulk insert solution